# How to access js and css files in resource directive in Laravel5

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, resources

I have js and css files in resource directive(resource dir that consists of asset, views,land dirs).
I need to load js and css files from views/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move these CSS, JS and image files to the `public` directory to be able to use them. Or, a better way is to use [Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir) to build assets and put them into the `public` directory automatically.

When your assets are in the `public` directory, you can access then by using `asset()` helper:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/image.png') }}">
```

This will generate an URL for the image like `https://yourwebsite.com/img/image.png`

Comment: Thanks. I know it's the right way, but I have to store js and css files in resource dir surely.

Comment: @WhiteSnow you can store them in this directory, but then you'll need to use Elixir which will concatenate/minify etc your assets and put them into the `public` directory.

Comment: Let me explain my situation.
I have static html project working well.
And I have to integrate it with Laravel project.
What I have to do is to show html in Laravel project simply.
The Html project have many html files and these htmls file load many css and js files.
So If I use Public dir, I have to seperate js and css dir from Html project and change urls in all html files.

Comment: @WhiteSnow when you're using Laravel, you point the web server to the `public` directory, so any user will have an access to only files which are in this directory. If you DON'T want to do that right, you can create a symlink between `resource/assets` and `public` directory.